# I want to align two consecutive align environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 &f(x) = y \\
 &f(g(x)) = g(y) \\
 &15
\end{align*}
Here is some text commenting on the similarity of these two sets of equations    .
\begin{align*}
 &f'(x) = y' \\
 &f'(g'(x)) = g'(y) \\
 &15000
\end{align*}
But now the bottom align* is just a tiny bit to the left of the top one, which looks wierd.
\end{document}
```

Is there a good way to make these two aligns line up horizontally? Let me know if it's not clear what I'm going for here. I'm open to using something other than align* of course.

Comment: Use `\intertext{Here is some text commenting on the similarity of these two sets of equations    .}`

Comment: Or make `&f(g(x)) = g(y)\phantom{'''} \\ ` the second line of your first `align*`.